# French Dictionary on Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Essentially what I wanted my code to do is to have a user input a word. The code would then search through the dictionary (French_Dictionary), attempt to find that word and if successful, print the translation of that word.

I am a beginner to python, and I was just wondering whether anyone could help me understand at the very least the concepts needed to code these steps.

This is my code so far (essentially just formalities)

```
def opening_statement():
    print "Welcome to a French Dictionary"
    while True:
        print "Choose [1] (English to French)   or   [2] (French to English) "
        choice = input("Enter 1 or 2 ")
        if choice == 1:
                    print "You have selected the English to French Dictionary"
                    break
        elif choice == 2:
            print "You have selected the French to English Dictionary"
            break
        else:
            print "n/a"

def secondary_statement():
    while True:
        word = raw_input("Type your word: ")
        word = word.lower()
        print 'Please confirm - Your word is "%s"' % (word)
        answer= input("Yes [1]   or   No [2] ")
        if answer == 1:
            print "Translating..."
            break
        elif answer == 2:
            print "Repeating process..."
        else:
            print "n/a"

#Will add more and more words manually to dictionary
French_Dictionary = {
"aller" : "to go",
"avoir" : "to have"
}

print opening_statement()
print secondary_statement()
```

Comment: What is your question? StackOverflow is question/answer site, not an advice forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you the high level idea:

You use the english word as key in a translations dictionary to get the french version of the word:

```
>>> dictionary_of_words = {"yes":"oui", "no":"non"}
>>> dictionary_of_words["yes"]
'oui'
>>>
```

So, when you read a word as input, check if it is contained in the list of keys of the dictionary, and if it is, print the translation, else throw an exception for example.
To iterate over a dictionary, looping over the keys also works:

```
>>> list_keys = dictionary_of_words.keys()
>>> list_keys
['yes', 'no']
>>> for i in list_keys:
...     print dictionary_of_words[i]
... 
oui
non
>>>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to mask built-ins like `dict` and `list`.

Comment: and iterating on the keys is not very performant: iterate on the k,v tuple using `list_keys.items()` or on `list_keys.values()`

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate you're using a dictionary data structure for your dictionayr; if you're going to translate both ways, perhaps a different data structure is more appropriate? Something like 2 lists where you can link them via the indexes or something?

```
from functools import partial

eng = ["yes", "no"]

fr = ["oui", "non"]

def freng(fr, eng, mot):
    return eng[fr.index(mot)]

def engfr(fr, eng, word):
    return fr[eng.index(word)]

freng = partial(freng, fr, eng)
engfr = partial(engfr, fr, eng)
```

The partial function simplifies the calling signature so you can just have freng("oui") and get back "yes".

Notice the handling of cases where a word isn't in the dictionary; as it stands that would throw an exception. You may want to handle that more gracefully. Good luck!